# Access Gmail mails using oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get OAuth access to GMail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107563/get-oauth-access-to-gmail)

I want to create an application which can access gmail mails of others using google oauth 2.0, is it possible with this, or should i use any other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to this [article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/17/google-oauth-2-0-for-gmail-and-talk/) and this [blog post](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.se/2012/09/adding-oauth-20-support-for-imapsmtp.html), as of September 2012 you can use OAuth 2.0 to access Gmail over IMAP/SMTP and XMPP.