# Google OAuth scope for sending mail

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-oauth

Using Google Oauth2, the following scope is used to get API-access to a users email:
https://mail.google.com/

Testing the scope via [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) confirms that the app wants to "View and manage your email":

[image]

Is there a way to only ask for access to send emails on behalf of the user? A more specific scope perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that the answer is no. The [GMail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#oauth_20_scopes) specifies a single scope (https://mail.google.com) providing both read and write access. Not ideal IMO, would be nice to have independent read/write email access scopes.

FYI, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107563/get-oauth-access-to-gmail) in SO leads to the same conclusion for read-only email access.

Answer (score 20):

The scope is the same if you use OAuth through SMTP or IMAP. But Google released new set of scopes (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) for Gmail API access. Here they are:

1. https://mail.google.com/    Full access to the account, including permanent deletion of threads and messages. This scope should only be requested if your application needs to immediately and permanently delete threads and messages. All other actions can be performed with less permissive scopes.
2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify    All read/write operations except immediate, permanent deletion of threads and messages.
3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly  Read all resources and their metadata. No write operations.
4. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose   Create, read, update, and delete drafts. Send messages and drafts.
5. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send   Send messages only. No read or modify privileges on mailbox.
6. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert       Insert and import messages only.
7. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels       Create, read, update, and delete labels only.
8. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata     Read resources metadata including labels, history records, and email message headers, but not the message body or attachments.
9. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic       Manage basic mail settings.
10. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing   Manage sensitive mail settings, including forwarding rules and aliases. (GSuite only)

You can try using the 5th one and see if it works for you.

Comment: I tried the 5th today and I can't get it to work. I had to revert to the mail.google.com scope.

Comment: Now Google is restricting use of pretty much every gmail scope as well and forcing app developers to "prove" you need the scopes.  I went through this with them over 3 months back and forth with their "bots" asking for videos, confirmation you are following guidelines, etc.  In the end they revoked access to the my application.  I did post a question on this but no replies yet.  I can't believe there aren't more developers going through this.

Comment: @bvstone You can blame: https://www.theverge.com/2018/7/2/17527972/gmail-app-developers-full-email-access

Comment: @Kumar - Now THAT makes complete sense.  I had no idea that was happening.  Well, I guess I'll need to charge more for my product and make companies set up their own private gmail client id in their G Suite.  More time, more support, more money I guess.  And in my case, for the record, there was no way I could read email from my customers unless they gave me their credentials for testing anyhow.

Comment: @bvstone I am going through the exact same API scope verification process. I have asked Google to provide a sample code how to use the googleapis scopes correctly. I will post the answer here if they do so. I saw the article posted by Kumar, I can see why they are doing this as some irresponsible app developers misusing the gmail scope. If I am unable to implement the 'Compose' scope, I may have to use my own third party email provider, which would be disappointing.

Comment: Still fighting with them, this time mainly for the SMTP server and OAuth 2.0 which requires mail.google.com scope.  They told me to switch to use the API instead and use the .send scope instead.  Sure, change all my customers from the SMTP server to the API... sounds real productive.  Why they don't just change the scope on the SMTP server to .send I have no clue.  Anyhow, I'm abandoning trying to reason with Google.  I'm going to force my customers to set up their own applications in their own Google Apps and not allow using it for just gmail.com addresses.  Ridiculous.

Comment: We have the same problem: Google asks as to abandon the `https://mail.google.com/ ` scope and use the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send` scope which we'd love to do… but their systems can't cope with the change, their SMTP server still insists on the full access scope even though we made the change in the app and their management console. Back and forth for months, they don't respond for weeks and now Gmails mails our customers that our app will stop working with their Gmail accounts. The Gmail team is the most incompetent and opaque entity I've ever dealt with.

Comment: It's been 2 years and https:/ /www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send still does not allow you to send email.  The Gmail team is a joke.

Comment: @GregWittmeyer even in 2023 https:/ /www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send does not allow you to send email
More 2 years for you

Comment: The same for me in October 2023. I'm forced to use https://mail.google.com/. If I try to use https:/ /www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send the message is rejected by the SMTP server after XOAUTH2 authentication. I  did not try the publication as I'm still in development but I have a bad feeling now...

Comment: December 2023 same same (not different) [sigh...]